# puppeteer-page-proxy package not found on import

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I installed  [puppeteer-page-proxy](https://github.com/LeM0-Dev/puppeteer-page-proxy) by LeM0 using this like instructed on the page

```
npm i @lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy
```

Yet when I try to include it in my module, I get:

```js
const useProxy  = require('puppeteer-page-proxy');
```

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1042
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'puppeteer-page-proxy'
Require stack:
```

Or

```js
const useProxy  = require('lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy');
```

```
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy'
Require stack:
```

What is the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with the package, but it appears that `@lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy` is a fork of `puppeteer-page-proxy`, so the maintainer of the fork may have forgotten to update the readme.

Adding an `@` symbol to your second attempt works:

```js
const useProxy = require('@lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy');

console.log(useProxy);
```

Module syntax works too, as seen in [this snippet in the repo's issues](https://github.com/LeM0-Dev/puppeteer-page-proxy/issues/3#issuecomment-1936043107).

index.js:

```js
import useProxy from '@lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy';

console.log(useProxy);
```

package.json:

```json
{
  "type": "module",
  "dependencies": {
    "@lem0-packages/puppeteer-page-proxy": "^1.3.3"
  }
}
```

Command:

```bash
$ node index
[AsyncFunction: useProxy] { lookup: [AsyncFunction: lookup] }
```

I [opened a PR](https://github.com/LeM0-Dev/puppeteer-page-proxy/pull/4) to adjust their readme to use the correct import.

Note that based on [multiple](https://github.com/LeM0-Dev/puppeteer-page-proxy/issues/3#issuecomment-1936043107) [issues](https://github.com/LeM0-Dev/puppeteer-page-proxy/issues/1), the package doesn't work with the latest Puppeteer version at the time of writing, so you may need to downgrade Puppeteer and/or this package until that's resolved. I didn't verify this, but [this issue](https://github.com/LeM0-Dev/puppeteer-page-proxy/issues/1) claims Puppeteer 21.3 is the maximum supported version.

Comment: thank you for this... I realized I was missing ```@``` in the beginning... but again there is another problem which I will make another thread

Comment: @umarkaa Ah good call, so I guess require does work. I might not have tried it. I'll update to reflect that.